# How to use replace update in Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I have a category name A with path: 1-2-

and some children with path like:

B: 1-2-3-

C: 1-2-4-

D: 1-2-5-

I want to move category A from 1 to 6 with path: 6-2-

How can I update categories B,C,D to 6-2-%

I found this code for php:

UPDATE category SET path = REPLACE(path, '1-2-', '6-2-') WHERE path LIKE '1-2-%'

but I don't know how to use it for laravel.

Comment: please include your model structure

Comment: Categories::where('path','like',$oldpath.'%')->update([
     'path' => DB::raw("REPLACE('path', ".$oldpath.", ".$newpath.")")
 ]);
and i got error:
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ' 3-2-) where `path` like ?' at line 1 (SQL: update `orip_categories` set `path` = REPLACE('path', 1-2-, 3-2-) where `path` like 1-2-%)

Comment: Better paste that in your original question post :)

Comment: thank manniL, i edited my post.

Comment: if this code works use DB::raw command

Comment: @Rodrane hi Rodrane, it work like a charm. Awesome. Thanks so much. I spent so much of my time for this . Thanks again.

Comment: I will just make it an answer then :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if this code works you can use

```
DB::raw('UPDATE category SET path = REPLACE(path, '1-2-', '6-2-') WHERE path LIKE '1-2-%');
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do it like this:

```
DB::table("category")
->where("path", "LIKE", "1-2-%")
->update(["path" => DB::raw("REPLACE(path,  '1-2-', '6-2-')")]);
```

Or, If you have Model for category table:

```
Category::query()
->where("path", "LIKE", "1-2-%")
->update(["path" => DB::raw("REPLACE(path,  '1-2-', '6-2-')")]);
```